# Why crawler don't go next page?

Tags: c#, xpath, web-crawler

I've made this crawler, and I would like to know why my code to go to next page is not working. here comes the code.

```
        var pessoaFinder = new ABCTelefonosPessoasLinkFinder();
        var pessoaContent = new ABCTelefonosPessoasContentFinder();
        var Urls = DadoPo.ListarUrls();


        foreach (var url in Urls)
        {
            var tempPessoas = new List<string>();
            tempPessoas.AddRange(pessoaFinder.Find(url));

            foreach (var linkPessoa in tempPessoas)
            {
                var infoPessoa = new List<DadoTo>();
                infoPessoa.AddRange(pessoaContent.Find(url + linkPessoa));


                foreach (var pessoa in infoPessoa)
                {
                    if (DadoPo.VerificaLink(url + linkPessoa))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                   DadoPo.Salvar(pessoa);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This call the functions that call the functions taht find links, and go to next page. Here comes the function that find person information and goes to next page (where I think the error is).

```
    public string[] Find(string url)
    {
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);
        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='mainContent']/div/a");

        if (nodes == null)
        {
            return new string[0];
        }

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var href = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            cidades.Add(href);
        }

        var elUrlProximaPagina = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mainContent']/div[@class='paginado']/div/*[contains(@class,'previous')]");

        if (elUrlProximaPagina == null)
        {
            return cidades.ToArray();
        }

        var urlProximaPagina = elUrlProximaPagina.GetAttributeValue("href", "");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlProximaPagina))
        {
            return Find(urlProximaPagina);
        }
        return cidades.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Please, as fast as you can answear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely problem is that writing `SelectSingleNode("//blah")` will result in searching the document from the root node every time and it will always return the first matching result regardless which node you start searching from. This causes you to keep selecting one node and re-crawling it. You should use the `.//` syntax to specify that you're searching from the current node: `SelectSingleNode(".//blah")`.

So your XPATH should be:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='mainContent']/div[@class='paginado']/div/*[contains(@class,'previous')]");
```

You also have to **fix all other XPATH selectors in your code** so that you select from the current node, not from the root node.

Comment: Thank you for your answear and attention!